# I can upload files to Azure blob storage from localhost, but it doesn't work when running as a web app on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, file-upload, blob

I wrote a web service with ASP.NET Core 6.0 to upload files to Azure blobs. When I run this service from localhost, it uploads the file. However, when I try to run the service as a web app on Azure, I get the following error:

"Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (Name or service not known (myaccount.blob.core.windows.net:443)) "

Comment: Are you trying to upload to same storage account from both places? Is your storage account behind a firewall?

Comment: Hows your RetryPolicy looks like could you please share that as well?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes same account and same code

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I didn't set any retry policy. I used default policy.

Comment: Did you had the chances to look into your application logger? Is there any connection failure message? I think, please have a try with [`setting up retry configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-retry-policy#configure-retry-options) if that resolve the issue, I would suggest, please [`try this configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-retry-policy#configure-retry-options) if something change in behaviour.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code which worked for me in Azure Portal :

**`Pragram.cs:`**

```
using WebApplication31;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AzureBlobService>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**`AzureUploader.cs:`**

```
namespace WebApplication31
{
    public class AzureUploader
    {
        public string? FileName { get; set; }

        public FileStream? Stream { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`AzureBlobService.cs:`**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;


namespace WebApplication31
{
    public class AzureBlobService
    {
        BlobServiceClient bc;
        BlobContainerClient cc;
        string aConnString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=pPBTMJEURZ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        public AzureBlobService()
        {
            bc = new BlobServiceClient(aConnString);
            cc = bc.GetBlobContainerClient("container name");
        }

        public async Task<List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
        {

            var aResponse = new List<Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo>>();
            foreach (var file1 in files)
            {
                string fileName1 = file1.FileName;
                using (var memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file1.CopyTo(memoryStream1);
                    memoryStream1.Position = 0;
                    var client1 = await cc.UploadBlobAsync(fileName1, memoryStream1, default);
                    aResponse.Add(client1);
                }
            };

            return aResponse;
        }

    }
}
```

**`WeatherForecastController.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication31.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        AzureBlobService _ser;
        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, AzureBlobService services)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _ser = services;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadBlobs(List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            var res = await _ser.UploadFiles(files);
            return Ok(res);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Blob added successfully:`**

[image]